# Default settings for CScript.exe

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd, wsh

How can I make `CSript.exe` run my scripts with `/K` by default?

Also is it possible to set default settings for how will the `cmd` window appear?(maximise window, pick font, size etc.)

UPDATE:

I heard about this switch `/K` in context of running `cmd.exe`. What I am trying to achieve is to have my window to remain open after script finishes or quits due to an error.

Comment: [`cscript.exe` doesn't have a `/K` command line switch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490816.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), I assume you are talking about `cmd.exe /K`?

Comment: yes that is where I hear about this switch.

Comment: @sgp667 Edit your question and post your code

Answer (score 0):

Next setting could help: `Open3` or `Open4` might match your requirement…

- `Open`  (default: open with WScript.exe on double click)
- `Open2` Open with Command Prompt
- `Open3` CScript && stay open
- `Open4` CScript && pause && close

`reg` query:

```
==> for %G in ("" 2 3 4) do @reg query HKCR\VBSFile\Shell\Open%~G /S

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open\Command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    "%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*


HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    Open &with Command Prompt
    MUIVerb    REG_EXPAND_SZ    @%SystemRoot%\System32\wshext.dll,-4511

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2\Command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    "%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe" "%1" %*


HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open3
    (Default)    REG_SZ    CScript && stay open

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open3\Command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /S /K " "C:\Windows\System32\CScript.exe" "%1" "


HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open4
    (Default)    REG_SZ    CScript && pause && close

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open4\Command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /S /C " "C:\Windows\System32\CScript.exe" "%1" & pause"
```

`regedit` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell]
@="Open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,57,00,\
  53,00,63,00,72,00,69,00,70,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,\
  00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2]
@=hex(2):4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,26,00,77,00,69,00,74,00,68,00,20,00,43,\
  00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,61,00,6e,00,64,00,20,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,6d,00,70,00,\
  74,00,00,00
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,77,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,78,00,74,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  34,00,35,00,31,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,43,00,\
  53,00,63,00,72,00,69,00,70,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,\
  00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open3]
@="CScript && stay open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open3\Command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe\" /S /K \" \"C:\\Windows\\System32\\CScript.exe\" \"%1\" \""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open4]
@="CScript && pause && close"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open4\Command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe\" /S /C \" \"C:\\Windows\\System32\\CScript.exe\" \"%1\" & pause\""
```